# Build cpptest unit test framework on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have successfully build and used cpptest on windows. Downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpptest/. Now I want to build same on Linux platform. but I am not able to build because config.h file is not present in downloaded zip file which is used inside collectoroutput.cpp. Can anyone guide me how I can build cpptest on Linux. zip folder has INSTALL.quick file but that is not working for me. Please find attached command on linux from INSTALL.quick and error on execution that command.[Command and error on execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujkGA.png)

Comment: why not just `sudo apt-get install libcpptest-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

Download **cpptest-1.1.2.tar.gz**
and unpack.

```
$ cd cpptest-1.1.2/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

works fine with ubuntu 16.04